# Ansible is getting stuck on some server which is in bad ps state?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook as shown below and it works fine most of the times. But recently what I am noticing is it is getting stuck on some of the servers from the **ALL** group and just sits there. It doesn't even move forward to other servers in the **ALL** list.

```
# This will copy files
---
- hosts: ALL
  serial: "{{ num_serial }}"
  tasks:
      - name: copy files
        shell: "(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com 'ls -1 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copy/stuff/*' | parallel -j20 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com:{} /data/records/')"

      - name: sleep for 5 sec
        pause: seconds=5
```

So when I started debugging, I noticed on the actual server it is getting stuck - I can ssh (login) fine but when I run `ps` command then it just hangs and I don't get my cursor back so that means ansible is also getting stuck executing above scp command on that server.

So my question is even if I have some server in that state, why not just Ansible times out and move to other server? IS there anything we can do here so that ansible doesn't pause everything just waiting for that server to respond.

Note server is up and running and I can ssh fine but when we run `ps` command it just hangs and because of that Ansible is also hanging.

Is there any way to run this command `ps aux | grep app` on all the servers in **ALL** group and make a list of all the servers which executed this command fine (and if gets hang on some server then time out and move to other server in ALL list) and then pass on that list to work with my above ansible playbook? Can we do all this in one playbook?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to solve the wrong problem.  In my experience you only see commands like ps hang when you have a major fault in the server.  Most common issues I've seen are a failing disk or hard mounted NFS share... which would also be consistent with a process copying files hanging.  In this case you may find that ps only hangs once you've hit the disk fault... which won't happen until you've accessed the faulty disk/sector... which won't happen until you try to copy the files.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible doesn't have this feature and it might even be dangerous to have it. My suggestion in this case would be: see the failure, **rebuild the server**, run again.

It's possible to to build the feature you want in your playbook, what you could do is to have a dummy [async](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html) task that triggers the issue, and the verify the outcome of that. If the async task didn't finish in a reasonable time, use the [`meta: end_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html) task to move to the next host.

You might need to mark some of those tasks with `ignore_errors: yes`.

Sorry that I cannot give you a complete answer as I've never tried to do this.

Comment: yeah this sounds something I can try but I am also not sure how ansible playbook will look like for this purpose. Very new to ansible as of now.

Comment: I would add a [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) just for this and run it as close to the start of the playbook as possible.

Comment: do u think you can provide an example for this since I am pretty much new to this whole thing?

Comment: basically i want to run this command `ps aux | grep app` on all the boxes and make a list of all the servers in which this command is executed fine and then pass on that list to work with my above ansible playbook. Do all this in one playbook. is this possible anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html) to achieve your goal. By default:

> Plays run with a linear strategy, in which all hosts will run each
>   task before any host starts the next task

By using the free strategy, each host will run until the end of the play as fast as it can. For example:

```
---
- hosts: ALL
  strategy: free
  tasks:
      - name: copy files
        shell: "(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com 'ls -1 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copy/stuff/*' | parallel -j20 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com:{} /data/records/')"

      - name: sleep for 5 sec
        pause: seconds=5
```

Another option would be to use [timeout](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-timeout-command/) to run your command, then using [registers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) to process whether the command executed successfully or not. For example `timeout 5 sleep 10` returns 124 because of the timeout while `timeout 5 sleep 3` returns 0 because the command terminates before the timeout occurs. In an ansible script, you could use something like:

```
  tasks:
     - shell: timeout 5 ps aux | grep app
       register: result
       ignore_errors: True

     - debug:
         msg: timeout occured
       when: result.rc == 124
```

Comment: Can you provide an example basis on this if possible?

Comment: Thanks. I am more interested in your second solution. can you tell me how that will get integrated with my actual playbook? I mean the task you have is gonna tell which machine is fine and which one is not and basis on that my actual task should work on those machine right? How these two gets integrated?

Comment: You need to add these tasks and process the results as you see fit. You are the one that knows what needs to be done with the hosts that fail.

Comment: That part I understand but I dont understand how this work as of now so thats why I was confuse on how can I run my shell command only on those boxes in which `ps` process works fine.

Comment: You should run the script on all machines, then handle the faulty ones correctly.

Comment: Today I found a bad machine in the same state again and it was still hanging even with timeout command you have. Are you sure this should work? One thing to add is - it was stuck on `TASK [Gathering Facts]` before it can run any of my tasks in the playbook and it was not even moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

As told by"Alassane Ndiaye ", you can try below code snippet.
Where I  am giving condition when shell is not timeout

```
tasks:
     - shell: timeout 5 ps aux | grep app
       register: result
       ignore_errors: True

     - name: Run your shell command
       shell:  "(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com 'ls -1 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copy/stuff/*' | parallel -j20 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com:{} /data/records/')"
       when: result.rc != 124 && result.rc != 0
```

Comment: Today I found a bad machine in the same state again and it was still hanging even with timeout command you have. Are you sure this should work? One thing to add is - it was stuck on `TASK [Gathering Facts]` before it can run any of my tasks in the playbook and it was not even moving forward.